# scrollview position changed from portrait to landscape

Tags: android

I am developing an app. The problem is scrollview position changes in landscape mode in respect to portrait mode. I have no idea for this. I am new in android. Pls help me.

Comment: What do you mean by scrollView position. Did you put your activity in portrait mode or not??

Comment: please be clear with your question and try to post your code

Comment: You mean it goes back to the top? That's normal as the activity is recreated on configuration change.

Comment: yes thats the problem. I want to save scrollview position while changing portrait to landscape or vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this in your activity class.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
outState.putFloatArray("ScrollViewContainerScrollPercentage",
        new float[]{
                (float) scrollView.getScrollX()/scrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth(),
                (float) scrollView.getScrollY()/scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight() });
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
final float[] scrollPercentage = savedInstanceState.getFloatArray("ScrollViewContainerScrollPercentage");
final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        scrollView.scrollTo(
                Math.round(scrollPercentage[0]*scrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth()),
                Math.round(scrollPercentage[1]*scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight()));
    }
});
}
```